# What is the SQL syntax to convert a Date with hours and minutes into the first day of its month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have a column called `Created` in one of my tables.

The `Created` column has dates in the `datetime` format: `2014-02-08 14:01:20.347`

I need to convert the dates into the following format.
For example, if date is `2014-02-08 14:01:20.347`, then I need it to become `2014-02-01 00:00:00.000`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`datefromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select datefromparts(year(created), month(created), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, date_column), 0)
```